# Why does it return null on the stripe API in PHP?

Tags: php, api

i'm trying to var dump the $response of my code bellow but it returns null and I don't know why...

```
$token = $_POST['stripeToken'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$name = $_POST['name'];


if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && !empty($name) && 
!empty($token)){ 
$ch = curl_init();

$data = [
    'source' => $token, 
    'description' => $name, 
    'email' => $email
];



curl_setopt_array($ch, [

    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers', 
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true, 
    CURLOPT_USERPWD => 'sk_test_************************', 
    CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($data)

]);

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));

curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);

die();

}
```

For info, the $_POST variables are in another file and I verified that are filled with the informations of the form.

Hope someone can help

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Dump the return value of `curl_exec($ch)` before calling `json_decode` on it. Also, check [`json_last_error`](http://php.net/json_last_error).

Comment: It dosen't return any error for json_last_error

I dit var_dump(curl_exec($ch)); and it returned false

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "source=" . $token . "&email=" . $cEmail);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'sk_test_xxxxxxxxxx' . ':' . '');

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
$obj = json_decode($result);
curl_close($ch);
$customer = $obj->id;
```

You are welcome :)